# How can I generalise code which produces a modal image to process multiple images

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

My end objective is to produce a web page of small images which are clickable. When clicked, a modal image of the small image is displayed.

I copied the following code from the W3Schools site:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function(){
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
 /* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
#myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    padding: 10px 0;
    height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
 <!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img id="myImg" src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

  <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">

  <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

I can see that the code is hard-coded to one image and I think the easiest way to achieve my goal is pass the id of the image to the js script. So I've begun modifying the html thus:

```html
<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<img class="images" id="img_1" src="images/Cairns1-041-3-Water-Safari.gif" alt="Water Travellers" width="300" height="200">
<img class="images" id="img_2" src="images/Cairns1-047-2-Handle-With-Care.gif" alt="Manhandle" width="300" height="200">
<!-- img_3 etc -->
```

Am I on the right track and if so, how do I pass the image id to the script?  Part of my objective is to understand the code as much as possible rather than to just copy a plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

> Here's a JSfiddle I've made that shows how my answer can be merged with the question. Hopefully, it can help anyone else that's using w3schools. https://jsfiddle.net/bdneyq4s/1/

Yes, you're on the right track, although ID's aren't necessary if you set up an event observer.

You need to add the data that's needed to show the big version of the image in the modal. (If you're using the same image for the modal + the thumbnail, then don't worry about using the extra attribute)

For example, you can have something like:

```
<img class="modal-image" src="path/to/thumbnail.jpg" alt="Caption to show" data-bigImage="path/to/big-image.jpg" />
```

Then you can create an event observer that'll listen to an on-click event on all elements that use the `modal-image` class. From there you can grab the `data-bigImage` and `alt` attributes from the clicked on element and populate the modal's content with it.

You said you didn't want to copy and paste code so I didn't write out the Javascript that'll do it, but if you need me to, I'll edit my answer to show some examples on how it can be done.

EDIT: I've added the following snippet to show a very basic example of how it can be done. I've made an event observer for each image with the `modal-image` class and replace the image in the modal with the new image attributes. (You can click on the little thumbnails to see it work)

```js
// Select all images that have the class modal-image
var image = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-image");

// to set an event observer on each element
for( var i=0; i<image.length; i++ ){
  image[i].onclick = function() {
   // get the two values we need from the image
    // i'm using the alt as the caption
  var 
      bigImage = this.getAttribute('data-bigImage'),
      caption = this.getAttribute('alt');
    
  replaceModalImage( bigImage, caption );
  }
}


/*
 * Replace the modal image's source in order to display the new image
 *
 * @param src Source of the new image
 * @param caption Caption to show with the modal
*/
function replaceModalImage( src, caption ){
 var 
   img = document.getElementById('big-image'),
    captionContainer = document.getElementById('caption');
  
  img.setAttribute('src', src);
  img.setAttribute('alt', caption);
  captionContainer.innerHTML = caption;
  
}
```

```css
.modal-image{
  /* this is just to make it small like a thumbnail, use a small image in production */
  width: 100px; 
}

img{
  max-width: 100%;
}

#modal{
  background: #999;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!-- thumbnail container -->
<div class="thumbnails">
  <!-- src = small image, data-bigImage = big image src -->
  <img class="modal-image" src="http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/geometry-dash/images/4/4b/GearSawblade01.png" alt="Caption to show" data-bigImage="http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/gear-8.png" />
  <img class="modal-image" src="https://ak1.ostkcdn.com/images/products/6626651/6626651/Cottage-Oak-Dining-Table-P14192779.jpg" alt="Caption to show" data-bigImage="http://www.ikea.com/PIAimages/0106117_PE253936_S5.JPG" />
</div>

<!-- modal html -->
<div id="modal">
  <div id="image"><img id="big-image" src="" alt="" /></div>
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks verey much h3raldo. Yes, would you kindly supply the Javascript that'll do it?

Comment: @Trevor, I edited my answer to include an example snippet. Let me know if that explains it enough. I've excluded the actual modal functionality since it looks like you have that part down.

Comment: I can't merge your answer (the selection) with the modal display code. I have tried. Would you be able to look at what I've done? If so, how do I add code to this post again?

Comment: @Trevor, I've added a JSfiddle to the top of my answer that merges your code with the answer I posted. Let me know if that works for you!